# How to allow only iPhone 5 or later devices to use app since it uses 720p HD front camera?

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, device, required

My app needs 720p Facetime HD front camera for video recording, so it can be run only on iPhone 5 or later devices (or iPod touch 5 generation or later)

UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key have only front-facing-camera value. How can I specify that front camera should be 720p HD?

Answer (score 0):

You can play with the screen dimensions in this way:

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){

    CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    result = CGSizeMake(result.width * scale, result.height * scale);

    if(result.height != 960){  //height equal to 960 in devices earlier than iPhone 5
        //access the camera
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for answer!  I find [this](https://gist.github.com/Jaybles/1323251) method to determine device model